# Google Chrome memory saver - command line switch?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-arguments

I'd like to automatically turn on memory saver option in Google Chrome on my Windows machines.

Is there a command line switch that does it? I did some research but no success.

Alternatively, any guess where Chrome keeps this setting stored? Typically all user settings are stored in the "Preferences" file (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences), but in this case apparently not (I tried copying this file to another user, but it didn't turn on the mem-saver mode, although in the original profile it was active.)

Answer (score 0):

The setting seems to be here: `"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"`

```
{
    "autofill": {
        "states_data_dir": "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\AutofillStates\\2020.11.2.164946"
    },
    "background_mode": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "browser": {
        "enabled_labs_experiments": [
            "memory-saver-multi-state-mode@1"
        ],
        "has_shown_refresh_2023_whats_new": true,
        "last_redirect_origin": "",
        "last_whats_new_version": 119,
        "shortcut_migration_version": "86.0.4240.75"
    },
    "data_use_measurement": {
        "data_used": {
            "services": {
                "background": {},
                "foreground": {}
.....
```

With the setting on `Default` it shows: `"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":[]`

`Enabled` shows: `"enabled_labs_experiments": ["memory-saver-multi-state-mode@1"]`